# Why not just chop off the head of the Leviathan posing as Dick Roman?

Tags: supernatural

In the television series, Supernatural, in Season 7, it is established that a Leviathan can be killed (or at-least nicely dealt with) by chopping the head off and keeping it's head and body far apart.

Anyhow, in the last few episodes of the Season, we see that Dean and Sam working hard to get the blood of the King of the Hell, the alpha Vampire and what not.

My question is why not just chop Dick's head off in the same way as they have done for a few other Leviathan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Cut off the head and the body will die'

Killing Dick outright was necessary so the other Leviathans would die permenently and not regenerate when reunited with their heads.

This is never explicitly stated, and the only leviathans we see later on in season eight are in purgatory, however I think this the the conclusion the show wants you to come to.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't "die".  The tablet said "Cut off the head, and the body will flounder"

Comment: I disagree. We are not informed as to the final fate of Leviathans who are not with Roman at the time. Nor do we know if their powers are reduced. All we know for certain is without Dick Roman, the Leviathan are far less creative, or adaptive and without leadership just become very nasty monsters. It was never stated they would lose their powers or abilities individually.

Comment: @Thaddeus no, its not stated, but I do think it is the conclusion the writers want us to come to.

Answer (score 5):

#### While the solution of "cutting off Dick's head" seemed easy enough, there was the nagging problem of getting through Dick's henchmen who were also Leviathans.

> **Leviathan**, also called the Old Ones, pre-date the creation of humans and angels, as well as the soul itself. They would also pre-date any beings with souls, such as monsters. They are therefore among the first creations of God.
>
> Death describes them as immensely powerful and hungry. Before God went on to create more creatures, however, He felt that the Leviathans threatened to consume and destroy everything "in God's petri dish". For this reason, Death states that God created Purgatory and sealed the Leviathans inside to contain them and their hunger.

- In the Supernatural order of things, Leviathans are not just bad-assed, they are the definition of the word.
- Leviathans can kill both demons and angels without breaking a sweat. Only an Archangel can give them pause. (And that does not mean the Archangel will assuredly win, only that the Leviathan might hesitate long enough to lose its head...)
- Leviathans were basically immortal unless bibbed (forced to eat themselves), poisoned with the Blood of the Fallen or eaten by another Leviathan. They can be temporarily (and this is important, only temporarily inconvenienced by borax, no explanation is given). Fates which would normally kill humans (a car dropped from overhead, for example) only causes them to discorporate into a black goo, and reconstitute themselves within the hour.

> **Blood of the Fallen**: The Word of God states that a Leviathan can be killed by a bone of a righteous mortal soaked in the blood of the fallen. There are three fallen whose blood is required; the first of these is a Fallen Angel (Castiel's blood qualifies). The other two Fallen are The Ruler of Fallen Humanity (meaning Crowley, The King of Hell) and a Father of Fallen Beasts (an Alpha). Once this weapon is assembled, the Leviathan only needs to be given a fatal blow to be killed, but it can result in those nearby being pulled to Purgatory with the Leviathan soul.

- Despite Sam and Dean's impressive record for "ganking" the threats of their Supernatural world, the Leviathan leader Dick Roman was both cunning and duplicitous. He kept a piece of the original Dick Roman and using it, he was even able to clone his appearance making it even harder to figure out which of the Leviathan was the real Dick Roman. Only an angel could tell the difference.

**So, chopping off Dick's head seems simple enough, EXCEPT FOR HIS:**

- superhuman strength, speed, stamina, ability to survive almost any injury,
- resistance to almost all mortal or supernatural weapons except for the Blood of the Fallen, which required gathering the resources required to kill him included, fighting or tricking, an Alpha (the best Vampire-kind has to offer), the head of the Demonic Underworld (Crowley) and finding a cooperative fallen Angel,
- secured compound filled with security systems, armed guards and replicated Dick Romans (also leviathans),
- being the leader of a pack of Darwinistically-determined, super-predators so dangerous even God took them out of the game and gave them their own extra-dimensional prison, should inform you that the task was not as easy as it might sound.

Comment: IIRC, it was said that Castiel could tell the difference because he'd had the leviathan inside him. I don't think it was ever said that ALL Angeles could tell the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Simple - well, not so simple - practicality.

If they just cut of Dick's head, there's a chance he can come back.  And the other Leviathan know this.

Eternal vigilance against *all Leviathan on the planet*, whose only goal is to rescue Dick (so they can have a leader again), is not a good plan.  And should they possibly succeed, they'll be more prepared for next time, making it even harder to do again.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Borax, which that affects Leviathans, but it is seen on some of the episodes, that Dick is not nearly as affected by that solution as the other "lower level" leviathans, so my guess would be that beheading Dick wouldn't work either, he's the main Leviathan, and he's shown to be stronger and more resilient than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

um...first off leviathans are one of gods first creations and can only be destroyed by 3 things god, MICHEALS Sword, and a bone of one truly innocent dripped in the blood of the Father of fall, ruler of the fallen and one of the fallen this blood can be given willingly but it also can be taken. borax only burns them and the reason for this is it is a pesticide like formula that kills normal sea creatures so since the leviathans are stronger than normal sea creatures the are more resistant the leviathans are gods second version of sea creatures the first being the Merpeople.

Comment: When were Merpeople mentioned on Supernatural? Did it really say that they came before the Leviathans, if they were?

Answer (score -1):

Except the fact that his strength super-ceeds that of all angels. I think Archangels can overpower low-ranking leviathan like Chet and possibly George, but as far as saying archangels stand a chance against high-ranking leviathan like Edgar, or Dick is kind ridiculous.

Comment: this does not answer the question and I think it should be a comment